# How do I solve a problem with opening the application menu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

I have a new problem that I can't find an answer to anywhere.
I am running Xubuntu 12.10 Xfce.
When I click on the top left icon, which is known as the Application menu, it gives me this error:

```
Failed to load the applications menu : Error on line 1 char 1: Document was empty or contained only whitespace.
```

Can someone please suggest any solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Removing and reading didn't help me, but after reading (but not trying) user63872's answer, I just deleted this one file:

```
~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu
```

and suddenly it worked again.

Answer (score -1):

That didn't work for me but copying the contents of `/etc/xdg/menus/` over the contents of `HOME/.config/menus/` as a merge/replace did, this reset the menu to a default layout and got it working again. I think the *main menu* editor may not have worked correctly for me and caused this error, but that's just a guess. There is probably a more specific way to fix but I don't know myself.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This seems to be an answer and not *just* a comment on another answer, but *which* answer are you saying *didn't* work? Please note that [Ask Ubuntu works very differently from a forum](http://askubuntu.com/about); there's no persistent *order* that answers appear.